# mod_rewrite pattern to handle a page with parameters

Tags: mod-rewrite

i'm really unable to understand how to handle this..
I have this URL: `mywebsite.com/product_search.aspx?area=6&category=46`

i want to redirect all request to

mywebsite.com

i have tried something like: `RewriteRule ^product_search.aspx(.*)$ / [L]` and `RewriteRule ^product_search.aspx([^/]+)$ / [L]`, but they are not working or redirect the page to `mywebsite.com/area=6&category=46`

Anyone can help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: .aspx is on Windows, mod-rewrite is an apache module, are you using apache in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my comment above, .aspx is on Windows, mod-rewrite is an apache module, are you using apache in Windows?

This will be a first approach for apache server, instructions to be inserted in .htaccess or vhosts or equivalent:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product_search\.aspx$ / [R=301,L]
```

It performs a redirection like this:

```
mywebsite.com/product_search.aspx?area=6&category=46
=> mywebsite.com/?area=6&category=46
```

Go get rid of all URL arguments, you can append **?** at the end of the result URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product_search\.aspx$ /? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! Apache is on a Linux machine. However i would like to get rid of all the parameters as they are from a very old website that no longer exist.. i would like to have the link redirected to mywebsite.com/

Comment: Thanks, still it doesn't work, there must be something else within my htaccess that does not do his job !

Comment: I've tested this rules set in Debian/Apache2 server, and it works?

Comment: I'm using CentOS/Apache2, i'm contacting support asking if someone has changed something that will break the rule. Hope to find a solution !!